# java.io.IOException: Failed to add a datanode. HDFS (Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, io, hdfs

I am faced with the error while appending file on HDFS (cloudera 2.0.0-cdh4.2.0).
The use case that cause an error is:

- Create file on file system (DistributedFileSystem). **OK**
- Append earlier created file. **ERROR**

  `OutputStream stream = FileSystem.append(filePath);
   stream.write(fileContents);`

  Then error is thrown:

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to add a datanode.

  User may turn off this feature by setting dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-  failure.policy in configuration, where the current policy is DEFAULT.  (Nodes: current=[host1:50010, host2:50010], original=[host1:50010, host2:50010])
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.findNewDatanode(DFSOutputStream.java:792)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.addDatanode2ExistingPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:852)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DFSOutputStream.java:958)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:469)`

Some related hdfs configs:

`dfs.replication` set to 2

`dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy` set to true
`dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure` set to DEFAULT

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by running on file system

```
hadoop dfs -setrep -R -w 2 /
```

Old files on file system had replication factor set to 3, 
setting `dfs.replication` to 2 in `hdfs-site.xml` will not solve the problem
as this config will not apply to already existing files.

So, if u remove machines from cluster you better check files and system replication  factor